# Can I connect from the real machine to a VPN inside a virtual machine?

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, vpn

I'm using a VPN that runs only on Windows. It's possible to use a virtual machine with Windows and connect the real pc through the virtual machine connection?

I've read about bridged adapter and proxy but I got a bit lost.. any help?

**EDIT:**

I'm on a Mac and I'm using Parallels.

Comment: Some information about your virtualization software and your exact setup would be helpful, but I can tell you that you can't do that with VMware Fusion, and probably with any VMware product, because a virtual network interface is created, and that interface is the one bound to the VPN connection, not the physical one.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Edited.

Comment: Would this apply to your situation:
http://www.pythian.com/blog/linux-desktops-windows-only-vpn-clients-virtual-machines-and-you-diy-vpn-jump-box/

Comment: @jaume: It's possible with VMWare, but you need to create the static routes and the NAT yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Parallels, so here is only a very high level description how you *could* do it, in case the bridge doesn't work:

1. Make sure the Windows system can reach the VPN portal (in your case this probably means: Windows has Internet access)
2. Make sure the Windows system has a private IP address on a virtual network adapter, e.g. `192.168.12.34` on `vmnet0` that you can `ping` from OS X.  It's okay if it's the same virtual network adapter that is used by Windows to access the Internet.
3. Inside Windows, create a Gateway/NAT.  Here's how: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469812.aspx (ignore the DHCP part, that's overkill)

Now you have all ingredients to reach the VPN from OS X.  So imagine this scenario: the VPN allows you to access some private IPs, say `172.16.123.0/24`.  You need to tell how OS X can reach `172.16.123.0/24` via `192.168.12.34`:

```
route -n add 172.16.123.0/24 192.168.12.34
```

Read here how to make that permanent: http://blog.irrashai.com/blog/2009/03/how-to-add-static-route-in-mac-os-x/

To troubleshoot and work through this `ifconfig` (not to change anything, just read the output), `man route`, `route` and `ping` are your friends. ;)